# First row from a table into Single Column - Sql Query

Tags: sql

Please look the below table,

```
RowID  Name    Age
1      Karhik  26
```

I want result in below format

```
Column1
1
Karthik
26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table table( RowID  int, Name varchar(10), Age int )
insert into @table
select 1,'Karhik',26
--Show original row
select * from @table
--Unpivot Row
select Value
from
(select cast(rowid as varchar(10)) as rowid, name, cast(age as varchar(10) )as age from @table) as x
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR [Column] IN 
      (rowid, name, age)
)AS unpvt
```